# rsa.encrypt в 1с

Tags: 1с, rsa

День добрый.
Есть кусок кода на JS. нужно сделать такое же в 1с.

```
    var rsa = new JSEncrypt();
    var vPublicKey = $("#PUBLIC_KEY").val();
    rsa.setPublicKey(vPublicKey);
    $("#crd_pan").val(rsa.encrypt($("#crd_pan1").val()));
```

Comment: а в чём проблема?

Comment: как это в 1с выглядит?

Comment: @ВадимТуманов Могу ошибаться, но в платформе 1c нет готовой реализации. Поэтому либо писать самому, либо подключать сторонние dll.

Answer (score 0):

Типовым решением подобных задач обычно является поиск аналогичного кода на Visual Basic/VBA и перенос его в 1С; См пример

```
e = Новый COMобъект("Excel.Application"); // e = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Но для этого dll содержащая объект должна быть зарегистрирована в Windows как COM-объект `regsvr32 Файл.dll`